# Resetting a Sveltekit form

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a form in a modal where I'm using `use:enhance` to prevent a page reload. If the form submission is successful I flip a boolean (`reserveSent`) to hide the form and show a thank you message.

```
$: if($page.form?.success){
      reserveSent = true
}
```

I have a close button which flips the boolean back and dispatches an event to the parent page to close the modal:

```
const closeModal = () => {
        reserveSent = false;
        dispatch("close");
}
```

This closes the modal, but if I open it again, `reserveSent` flips back to true, presumably because `form.success` is still true. I thought `use:enhance` reset the form, but perhaps it doesn't update the success setting? How can I set it manually or 'clear' it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either not re-using modals at all (creating them via [the client-API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api) and destroying them on close) or resetting the relevant data on open.

So when you open the modal you could just set `form.success`. The [`form` data](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#anatomy-of-an-action) is an export of the `+page.svelte` component, the `$page` store exposes it but it cannot be written to.

Personally, I would probably try to decouple the modal state, so it does *not* directly access page data, instead pass that in as properties as necessary. You can also add a callback via `enhance` ([see docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance)) to affect the modal more directly, once the submission is completed.

Comment: Your second point was the first thing I tried, but I can't figure how to do it. Straight up assignment eg `$page.form.success = false` throws an error (`set is not a function`)

Comment: Also I'm not sure if using the component API would reset the form store, as it is stored at page level ($page.form) as otherwise I can't check for form.success.

Comment: That is why I also wrote that separating it from the page data would be a good idea. I have not tried to work with modals that contain forms in SvelteKit before, so maybe there is no great pattern for integrating them. Having a reliance on the page just does not seem like a good idea but at the same time a modal cannot have its own `form` property that would be populated by an action result as that is conceptually bound to the page.

Comment: (I updated my answer in regards to `$page` not being writable. That would still be a hack though.)

Comment: By "separate from the page data" do you mean avoid using `+page.server.js` at all, and just, say, use a `server.js` endpoint?

Comment: Possibly, or handle the response of the action manually, rather than letting it go to the `form` property. You can add a handler in `enhance` to do so after all.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start with that, I guess i'll just go the `server.js` route

Comment: Setting `form = null` resets the form result. I guess you can't do that using the page store because it cannot be written to, as @ElendilTheTail mentioned. Maybe if you find a way to use the form in the modal instead of the store, or send a command to nullify the original form, then it could work.